# Recursively get all children of SAP Gui Session in c#

Tags: c#, sap-gui

I am looking to loop through all SAP GuiComponents in C# but am struggling to get all the children of children of a GUI session.

This is what I have so far (initially passing session.ActiveWindow.Children to nodes):

```
 private void IterateFindIDByNAme(GuiComponentCollection nodes, string searchstring)
    {
        if (foundID == "")
        {
            foreach (GuiComponent node in (GuiComponentCollection)nodes)
            {
                var comp = node;
                if (comp.Name.Contains(searchstring))
                    foundID = comp.Id;
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        FindIDByNAme((GuiComponentCollection)node, searchstring);
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Its able to get all the child elements of session.ActiveWindow but when trying to cast all the children to GuiComponentCollections its falling over.

This would be irrelevant if I could use the FindByName function but for some reason it is not working on the SAP screen I am currently working on (it does work on others, not sure why).

The ID of the field is:

```
wnd[0]/usr/subBCA_SUB_HEADER:SAPLBANK_BDT_CTRL:0100/subSUBS_DETAIL:SAPLBUSS:0028/ssubGENSUB:SAPLBUSS:4038/subA01P02:SAPLBCA_DYN_CN_CNMANO:0002/ctxtBCA_DYN_CONTRACT_ORGENTRY-ORGUNIT
```

and the function I am trying is:

```
((GuiTextField)session.FindByName("BCA_DYN_CONTRACT_ORGENTRY-ORGUNIT", "GuiTextField")).Text = "Test";
```

The findbyid works fine, but not findbyname?

I know this is 2 questions, but kind of related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **ctxt**BCA_DYN_CONTRACT_ORGENTRY-ORGUNIT

The type of the control is a `GuiCTextField` not <s>`GuiTextField`</s>:

```
session.FindByName("BCA_DYN_CONTRACT_ORGENTRY-ORGUNIT", "GuiCTextField")
```

---

Sample Code :

```
        public DateTime? GetModificationDate(int employeeID)
        {
            var session = SapHelper.GetActiveSession();

            Console.WriteLine("Recherche de la measure [A5 ou A6] avec un motif 90...");
            var window = session.BeginTransaction("PA20", "Afficher données de base personnel");
            window.FindByName<GuiCTextField>("RP50G-PERNR").Text = employeeID.ToString();
            window.FindByName<GuiCTextField>("RP50G-CHOIC").Text = "Mesures  (0000)";
            window.FindByName<GuiCTextField>("RP50G-SUBTY").Text = null;
            window.FindByName<GuiButton>("btn[20]").Press(); // list view

            if (window.Text == "Afficher données de base personnel")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(">> " + window.FindByName<GuiStatusbar>("sbar").Text);
                return null;
            }

            /*  Index Type          Title             Tooltip             
                0     GuiTextField  Début             Date de début       
                1     GuiTextField  Fin               Date de fin         
                2     GuiCTextField Mes.              Catégorie de mesure 
                3     GuiTextField  Dés. cat. mesure  Dés. cat. mesure    
                4     GuiCTextField MotMe             Motif mesure        
                5     GuiTextField  Dés. motif mesure Dés. motif mesure   
                6     GuiCTextField Client            Statut propre client
                7     GuiCTextField Activité          Statut d'activité   
                8     GuiCTextField Paiement          Statut paiement part */
            var result = window.FindByName<GuiTableControl>("MP000000TC3000").AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Start = x.GetText(0),
                    Category = x.GetCText(2),
                    CategoryText = x.GetText(3),
                    Reason = x.GetCText(4),
                    ReasonText = x.GetText(5),
                })
                .Where(x => (x.Category == "A5" || x.Category == "AG") && x.Reason == "90")
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (result == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(">> aucune measure [A5 ou A6] avec un motif 90 trouvée");
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(">> {0}:[{1}]{2} [{3}]{4}",
                    result.Start, result.Category, result.Category, result.Reason, result.ReasonText);
                return DateTime.ParseExact(result.Start, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }
```

Xy.Sap :

```
#region namespace Xy.Sap
namespace Xy.Sap
{
    using System.Reflection;
    using sapfewse;
    using saprotwr.net;
    using COMException = System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException;

    public static class SapHelper
    {
        public static GuiSession GetActiveSession()
        {
            var rot = new CSapROTWrapper().GetROTEntry("SAPGUI");
            if (rot == null)
                throw SapException.NotOpened();

            var app = (GuiApplication)rot.GetType().InvokeMember("GetScriptingEngine", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, rot, null);
            var connectedSession = app.Connections.Cast<GuiConnection>()
                .SelectMany(x => x.Children.Cast<GuiSession>())
                .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Info.User))
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (connectedSession == null)
                throw SapException.NotOpened();

            return connectedSession;
        }
    }

    public class SapException : Exception
    {
        public SapException(string message) : base(message) { }

        public static SapException NotOpened()
        {
            return new SapException("Veuillez lancer le SAP et de connecter avec votre identité");
        }
    }

    public static class SapExtensions
    {
        #region GuiSession

        /// <summary>
        /// Shortcut for PA20 query
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="session"></param>
        /// <param name="employeeID"></param>
        /// <param name="it">Infotype ID</param>
        /// <param name="sty">Subtype ID</param>
        /// <param name="asListView"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static GuiFrameWindow QueryPA20(this GuiSession session, int employeeID, string it, string sty = null, bool asListView = false)
        {
            var window = session.BeginTransaction("PA20", "Afficher données de base personnel");
            window.FindByName<GuiCTextField>("RP50G-PERNR").Text = employeeID.ToString();
            window.FindByName<GuiCTextField>("RP50G-CHOIC").Text = it;
            window.FindByName<GuiCTextField>("RP50G-SUBTY").Text = sty;
            window.FindByName<GuiButton>(asListView ? "btn[20]" : "btn[7]").Press();

            if (window.Text == "Afficher données de base personnel")
            {
                var exception = new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Failed to access to personal information of {0}", employeeID));
                exception.Data["Employee ID"] = employeeID;
                exception.Data["Infotype"] = it;
                exception.Data["Subtype"] = sty;
                exception.Data["View"] = asListView ? "ListView[Mont]" : "RecordView[Glasses]";
                exception.Data["Status Message"] = window.FindByName<GuiStatusbar>("sbar").Text;

                throw exception;
            }

            return window;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Shortcut for PA30 query
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="session"></param>
        /// <param name="employeeID"></param>
        /// <param name="it">Infotype ID</param>
        /// <param name="sty">Subtype ID</param>
        /// <param name="asListView"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static GuiFrameWindow QueryPA30(this GuiSession session, int employeeID, string it, string sty = null)
        {
            var window = session.BeginTransaction("PA30", "Gérer données de base HR");
            window.FindByName<GuiCTextField>("RP50G-PERNR").Text = employeeID.ToString();
            window.FindByName<GuiCTextField>("RP50G-CHOIC").Text = it;
            window.FindByName<GuiCTextField>("RP50G-SUBTY").Text = sty;
            window.FindByName<GuiButton>("btn[6]").Press();

            if (window.Text == "Gérer données de base HR")
            {
                var exception = new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Failed to access to personal information of {0}", employeeID));
                exception.Data["Employee ID"] = employeeID;
                exception.Data["Infotype"] = it;
                exception.Data["Subtype"] = sty;
                exception.Data["Status Message"] = window.FindByName<GuiStatusbar>("sbar").Text;

                throw exception;
            }

            return window;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Start a new transaction and return the active window
        /// </summary>
        public static GuiFrameWindow BeginTransaction(this GuiSession session, string transactionID, string expectedTitle)
        {
            return session.BeginTransaction(transactionID,
                x => x.Text == expectedTitle,
                x =>
                {
                    var exception = new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Failed to open transaction : {0}", transactionID));
                    exception.Data["Transaction ID"] = transactionID;
                    exception.Data["Expected Title"] = expectedTitle;
                    exception.Data["Current Title"] = x.Text;
                    exception.Data["Status Message"] = x.FindByName<GuiStatusbar>("sbar").Text;

                    return exception;
                });
        }
        public static GuiFrameWindow BeginTransaction(this GuiSession session, string transactionID, Predicate<GuiFrameWindow> validation, Func<GuiFrameWindow, string> errorFormatter)
        {
            return session.BeginTransactionImpl(transactionID, validation, x => new Exception(errorFormatter(x)));
        }
        public static GuiFrameWindow BeginTransaction(this GuiSession session, string transactionID, Predicate<GuiFrameWindow> validation, Func<GuiFrameWindow, Exception> errorBuilder)
        {
            return session.BeginTransactionImpl(transactionID, validation, errorBuilder);
        }
        private static GuiFrameWindow BeginTransactionImpl(this GuiSession session, string transactionID, Predicate<GuiFrameWindow> validation, Func<GuiFrameWindow, Exception> errorBuilder)
        {
            // force current transaction to end, preventing any blocking(eg: model dialog)
            session.EndTransaction();

            session.StartTransaction(transactionID);
            var window = session.ActiveWindow;
            if (!validation(window))
                throw errorBuilder(window);

            return window;
        }

        #endregion
        #region GuiFrameWindow

        public static TSapControl FindByName<TSapControl>(this GuiFrameWindow window, string name)
        {
            try
            {
                return (TSapControl)window.FindByName(name, typeof(TSapControl).Name);
            }
            catch (COMException e)
            {
                var writer = new StringWriter();
                writer.WriteLine("The control could not be found by name and type.");
                writer.WriteLine("Name : " + name);
                writer.WriteLine("Type : " + typeof(TSapControl).Name);

                throw new Exception(writer.ToString(), e);
            }
        }

        #endregion
        #region GuiTableControl

        /// <summary>Note: Do not iterate through this ienumerable more than once</summary>
        public static IEnumerable<GuiTableRow> AsEnumerable(this GuiTableControl table)
        {
            var container = table.Parent as dynamic;
            string name = table.Name, type = table.Type;
            int rowCount = table.VerticalScrollbar.Maximum;

            Func<GuiTableControl> getTable = () => container.FindByName(name, type) as GuiTableControl;

            for (int i = 0; i <= rowCount; i++)
            {
                getTable().VerticalScrollbar.Position = i;
                yield return getTable().Rows.Item(0) as GuiTableRow;
            }
        }

        public static TSapControl GetCell<TSapControl>(this GuiTableRow row, int column)
        {
            return (TSapControl)row.Item(column);
        }
        public static string GetCText(this GuiTableRow row, int column)
        {
            return row.GetCell<GuiCTextField>(column).Text;
        }
        public static string GetText(this GuiTableRow row, int column)
        {
            return row.GetCell<GuiTextField>(column).Text;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
#endregion
```

EDIT: The link to the LINQPad script  mentioned in comment below no longer works. I have re-uploaded it [here](https://gist.github.com/Xiaoy312/7e228764c34d5debf08c7ecf8ca7a9cc).

This script helps you to browse SAP GUI:

- List control type, name, id, content
- List properties and methods
- Highlight control
- Generate selector : `.FindByName<GuiTableControl>("MP000000TC3000")`

Comment: thank you!!! wasted so much time for such a simple answer. always forget about posting own questions when cant find answer.....

Comment: do you think its worth opening another question. as still think might be useful to know the first part of my question?

Comment: Did you intend to use it for debugging?

Comment: yea exactly. if i could loop, i would have been able to find the type/name. unless there is a tool that lets me interrogate SAP. bear in mind, I've not got any privileges to install anything.

Comment: I've written a script in LINQPad for that purpose. You can find it here : https://gist.github.com/Xiaoy312/a1424bd34acae92554105b27b0c80971

Comment: do i need to install linqpad then? or can i somehow run it in VS 2015 which i have installed?

Comment: It is a simple script that allows your to browse the active sap window, generate selector like `.FindByName<GuiLabel>("RP50G-PERNR")`, debug table.

Comment: awesome work!! works perfectly! and will save so much time.

Comment: not sure if still working on this/or want feedback.. but if could see all fields in a tree or view all fields at once would be handy.

Comment: love the extension methods! do you have a sample project... ive just copied pasted the linqpad code into my project.

Comment: cheers. im now getting error when looping through connections. var connectedSession = app.Connections.Cast<GuiConnection>() saying unable to cast....

Comment: That's strange. I guess the SAP ROT Wrapper we use is different then. In that case, just use what you use to obtain `session`, and forget my `GetActiveSession()`.

Comment: thats what im doing. mine was similar to your gist which also didnt work for some reason.... only difference i can see is my two lines: //// GuiConnection connection = sapGuiApp.Connections.ElementAt(0) as GuiConnection;
          ////  return connection.Sessions.ElementAt(0) as GuiSession;

Comment: as for cast not working. its because i didnt include "using System.Linq;"

Comment: what mean? number of comments? tried to do chat but my rep isnt high enough.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants to know how to get child elements of any gui component (this will simply write all ids to the console):

```
private void LoopAllElements(GuiComponentCollection nodes)
    {
        foreach (GuiComponent node in (GuiComponentCollection)nodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.Id);
                if (node.ContainerType)
                {
                    var children = ((node as dynamic).Children as GuiComponentCollection);
                    LoopAllElements(children);
                }
        }
    }
```

This will loop through all child elements of any GUIComponentCollection you pass to it such as

```
LoopAllElements(session.Children)
```

There is probably a better linq way of doing this but this should get you started.

Please also check out this gist created by Xiaoy312 https://gist.github.com/Xiaoy312/a1424bd34acae92554105b27b0c80971

this has a lot of useful functions to debug your current sap session which i have found extremely useful.

You can either view the code as it has a number of functions you can use such as improved findbyid and findbyname or run it in linqpad https://www.linqpad.net/Download.aspx which will allow you to interogate the current SAP session.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly we have to manually start SAP Logon to make line below working:

```
var rot = new CSapROTWrapper().GetROTEntry("SAPGUI");
```

Am I right?

If so maybe someone can explain me why at the line:

```
var app = (GuiApplication)rot.GetType().InvokeMember("GetScriptingEngine", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, rot, null);
```

I am getting exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
>   occurred in System.Dynamic.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))

I've already tried to change target platform from Any CPU to x86 and x64 and didn't have success in resolving this problem.

But when I run SAPGUI using following script:

```
var SapGuiApp = new GuiApplication();
string development = "Development ERP System";
var connection = SapGuiApp.OpenConnection(development);
```

instead of running SAP Logon manually described above problem is not reproducing.

But in this case I have other problem: GUI is different and for second option GUI looks corrupted - some of GUI controls are not displayed (please see screenshot). Please give me advice what can be wrong? Thank you in advance
[image]

UPDATE: I found solution that solves issue described below. You have to use object instead of var while you are trying to get session connection:

```
CSapROTWrapper sapROTWrapper = new CSapROTWrapper();
        object rot = sapROTWrapper.GetROTEntry("SAPGUI");
        object engine = rot.GetType().InvokeMember("GetScriptingEngine", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, rot, null);
        GuiConnection connection = (engine as GuiApplication).OpenConnection(connectionName);
        GuiSession session = connection.Children.ElementAt(0) as GuiSession;
```